# Cleaning .csv text data in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have recently created a python program that would import my finances from a .csv file and transfer it onto google sheets. However, I am struggling to figure out how to fix the names that my bank gives me.

Example:
`ME DC SI XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX NETFLIX` should just be `NETFLIX`,
`POS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX STEAM PURCHASE` should just be `STEAM` and so on

Forgive me if this is a stupid question as I am a newbie when it comes to coding and I am just looking to use it to automate certain situations in my life.

```
import csv
from unicodedata import category
import gspread
import time

MONTH = 'June'
# Set month name

file = f'HDFC_{MONTH}_2022.csv'
#the file we need to extract data from

transactions = []
# Create empty list to add data to

def hdfcFin(file):
    '''Create a function that allows us to export data to google sheets'''
    with open(file, mode = 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            date = row[0]
            name = row[1]
            expense = float(row[2])
            income = float(row[3])
            category = 'other'
            transaction = ((date, name, expense, income, category))
            transactions.append(transaction)
        return transactions
        
sa = gspread.service_account()
# connect json to api
sh = sa.open('Personal Finances')

wks = sh.worksheet(f'{MONTH}')

rows = hdfcFin(file)

for row in rows:
    wks.insert_row([row[0], row[1], row[4], row[2], row[3]], 8)
    time.sleep(2)
    # time delay because of api restrictions
```

Comment: Please show us some example data.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to split a string at spaces and take the last item? (No, then you would get `PURCHASE`. How is your code supposed to know that you want `STEAM` instead of `PURCHASE`?)

Comment: You probably need to provide a few more examples - your logic could be something like "first word of 4 or more characters in the string", or "first word of 4 or more characters if word not in ['PURCHASE', 'TRANSACTION', 'PAID', ...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont have specific format to identify the name then you can use below logic. Which will have key value pair. If key appears in name then you can replace it with value.

```
d={'ME DC SI XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX NETFLIX':'NETFLIX','POS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX STEAM PURCHASE':'STEAM'}
test='POS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX STEAM PURCHASE'
if test in d.keys():
    test=d[test]
print(test)
```

Output:

```
STEAM
```

If requirement is to fetch only last word out of your name then you can use below logic.

```
test='ME DC SI XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX NETFLIX'
test=test.split(" ")[-1]
print(test)
```

Output:

```
NETFLIX
```